# Using xssAPI in .js file cq5.6

Tags: javascript, xss, aem

Able to do it for jsp and java files, doubt how to make use of xssAPI.encodeForJSString("") in some .js file 
in adobe cq5.6

This is to do with xss issue reported by fortify tool 
for below code in js file

window.location.href = window.location.href + ("?mode=view");

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the AEM `xssAPI` at the front-end. It's an internal utility to be used by the AEM back-end code. There are other tools, more applicable to the use case you're describing.

Use the built-in function [`encodeUriComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) available in the browser.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3608791/1407656) for more information.

Comment: Yes was looking for something like this since xssAPI used in the backed.
Do we have validators for front end to be used like xssAPI.getValidHref()?